# Mobile REST API - only use POST in place of GET?

Tags: web-services, rest, post, mobile, get

A colleague and I were discussing the implementation of our REST API, and he mentioned that in his previous work they never used GET and instead used POST in place of that. His reasoning is that it promotes consistency; the client (a mobile device) does not need to worry about whether a certain API call is POST or GET, it can assume that it's a POST.

As I said this API is used by mobile devices, so the various browser specific differences between GET and POST don't apply (such as caching GET requests and having GET requests in browser history etc).

Does this have warrant? Still seems like bad practice to me. Can anyone explain the benefits of using both GET and POST instead of all POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not RESTful. One of the principles of REST is the [Uniform Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface). One constraint for this principle is *Identification of resources*:

> Individual resources are identified in requests, for example using URIs in web-based REST systems.

In the context of HTTP a resource is identified by a URI:

```
http://example.com/service/hotel/123/room/456
```

This URI identifies room 456 in hotel 1234. To interact with this resource, HTTP verbs are used. To get the state of the resource, `GET` is used. To change it, `PUT` is used. `POST` is used if a subresource of the resource is manipulated but how this pattern is used best is still open for discussion.

Proposing to only use `POST` for *every* interaction shows a complete lack of knowledge about REST. Most often people don't think "REST" and they don't think "resources" when the propose this. What they *do* think is Remote Procedure Call (RPC) which *can* be implemented over HTTP but has *nothing* do to with REST.

**Summary:** Don't use `POST` for everything. Model your resources and use the proper HTTP verbs.